# Azure Logic App ,set object variable in Array from Extract archive to folder FTP connector

Tags: arrays, ftp, azure-logic-apps

I have two **Input** & **Output** folders in FTP server.

***Please Note that I am using FTP connector in Logic app, Not SFTP connector. Through FTP connector we can not create dynamic folders in FTP server.***

Below are 2 input `.zip` sample files.

`File1.zip` :- (Contains `R1.xml` & `R2.xml`)

`File2.zip` :- (Contains `R3.xml` , `R4.xml` & `R5.xml`)

***In my Logic App I am doing below operations:-***

Logic app triggers when a `.zip` file is placed into **Input folder** and then that `.zip` file is extracted to **Output folder** using `"Extract archive to folder"` FTP connector.(Please Note that `.zip` file can contain multiple no. of `.xml` files as shown in the above example).
Then I read the `.xml` files from the **Output folder**.

**Logic App is required to run in concurrent mode so that for each .zip input file multiple instances can run in parallel.**

**Problem Statement :-**

When I am dropping 2 files `File1.zip` & `File2.zip` simultaneously in the Input folder, two instances of logic app is getting initiated at the same time corresponding to the each `.zip` file.

Please note that at this time in my output folder I have Unzipped files( `R1.xml` , `R2.xml` ,`R3.xml` , `R4.xml` & `R5.xml` ) from both the `.zip` files( `File1.zip` & `File2.zip` ).

**Now at this point in my for-each loop** (***Input for for-each loop is Body of Output folder***) for logic app instance(LA1) for `File1.zip`, it is required to pickup only `R1.xml` & `R2.xml`. Similarly for logic app instance(LA2) for `File2.zip`, it is required to pickup only `R3.xml`,`R4.xml` & `R5.xml`

But LA1 & LA2 both are reading all files( `R1.xml` , `R2.xml` ,`R3.xml` , `R4.xml` & `R5.xml` ) from the Output folder.

**Need Help to implement the below:-**

To fix this issue I want to fetch the file names & store it in an array. 
[image]

[image]

For example:-

for `File1.zip`, Array should contain only( `R1.xml` & `R2.xml` )

for `File2.zip`, Array should contain only( `R1.xml` , `R2.xml` & `R3.xml` )

Comment: Enable "Concurrency Control" in the setting of your "For each" and set the "Degree of Parallelism" to "1". Does this meet your needs ?

Comment: @HuryShen yes it's enable still it does not meet my requirement.

Comment: I noticed you have mentioned it in your question, but I just reconfirm if it can solve your problem. I will try to help you in some other ways.

Comment: @HuryShen No, it did not solve my problem even after setting "Degree of Parallelism" to "1" in for-each loop.

Comment: Hi Suraj, as you mentioned "Through FTP connector we can not create dynamic folders in FTP server", so if we create an azure function to create folder in FTP and call the function in logic app. Will this solve your problem ?

Comment: @HuryShen Actually we have thought of this solution but as per the requirement we are not supposed to create dynamic folders.

Comment: May I know if you use "List files in folder" action to list all of the files in output folder and loop them in "For each" action ?

Comment: Yes I am using "List files in folder" Action to list all the files in Output folder & loop them in for each loop. That why it is fetching all the files from Output folder irrespective of Logic app instance

Comment: Do you mind set your logic app to run just one instance at the same time ?

Comment: Yeah I have tested by setting logic app to run just by one instance at a time. In that case it works perfectly but as per requirement Logic App is required to run in concurrent mode so that for each .zip input file multiple instances can run in parallel.

Comment: By keep it in sequential we won't be able to leverage the benefit of Logic App in concurrent mode.
From end user perspective it will increase the Overall execution time of logic app In case of multiple files.

Comment: Is it possible to add another json file and include it in the zip file. This json file has the same name with the zip file. For example, the zip file is File1.zip, then the json file is File1.json and it is included in the zip file (so File1.zip contains R1.xml, R2.xml and File.json). The content of the json file is an array which contains the xml name in the zip file, such as ["R1.xml", "R2.xml"]. After the extract operation, we can loop the array in the json file by the same name with the zip file in your "For each" action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203290/discussion-between-suraj-sahoo-and-hury-shen).